# Why in some cases can I call a member function without an object?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working with a numerical library deal.ii, within which a lot of numerical tools are integrated. What I found weird is that I can call member functions directly without defining an object. For example, I can directly call

```
Vectortools::interpolate_boundary_condition();
```

Could you tell me when I can directly call the member functions without defining an object? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

There's two cases you can do this:

1. The member function is declared `static` -- in that case it is basically a free function but scoped to the class.  Notably, `this` cannot be used in a static function since an object is not required to invoke it.
2. When you are within a member function whose `this` pointer is implicitly convertible to a pointer to the type being invoked on (`Vectortools` in this case).  Note that this *is* invoked on an object (implicitly `*this`).  This can be used to invoke an inherited member that is being overridden or hidden:

   ```
   class A {
   public:
     virtual void foo();
   };

   class B : public A {
   public:
     virtual void foo() override;
   };

   void B::foo() {
     // Do something

     // Invoke the method we've overidden from A.
     A::foo();

     // Then do something else
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the function you are calling is a static function. A static function is a function which can be called without make an object of the class. You can only access static data members of class using static functions.